# Rock paper, scissors game

Tags: javascript

I just finished making a rps game on codecademy, and there are some extra tasks that include making an outcome if the user inputs wrong info. Basically, if you don't write an input of "rock", "paper" or "scissors" it will ask you again until you put in the right one.

How can i call userChoice variable until it gets the right answer. I tried it like this, but it just asks 2 times and then posts whatever you write.

```
var userChoice = prompt("Do you choose rock, paper or scissors?");

if (userChoice != "rock", "paper", "scissors") {
    userChoice = prompt("Do you choose rock, paper or scissors?");
}

var computerChoice = Math.random();
if (computerChoice < 0.34) {
    computerChoice = "rock";
} else if(computerChoice <= 0.67) {
    computerChoice = "paper";
} else {
    computerChoice = "scissors";
}

var compare = function (choice1, choice2) {
    if (choice1 === choice2) {
     return "The result is a tie!"; 
    }
    else if(choice1 === "rock") {
        if ( choice2 === "scissors") {
            return "rock wins";
        }
        else {
            return "paper wins";   
        }
    }
    else if(choice1 === "paper") {
        if(choice2 === "rock") {
            return "paper wins";   
        }
        else {
            return "scissors wins";   
        }
    }
    else if(choice1 === "scissors") {
        if(choice2 === "rock") {
            return "rock wins";
        }
        else {
            return "scissors wins";    
        }
    }
}

console.log("Human: " + userChoice);
console.log("Computer: " + computerChoice);
compare(userChoice, computerChoice);
```

Comment: You could massively simplify this - I had a little fun with it. Take a look at this, I've added comments to explain the shortcuts: http://jsfiddle.net/svArtist/12nLz7nb/

Comment: I will look into it tomorrow, thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a function that references itself:

```js
var userChoice = function () {
  var choice = prompt("Do you choose rock, paper or scissors?");

  if (choice !== "rock" && choice !== "paper" && choice !== "scissors") {
    return userChoice();
  } else {
    return choice;
  }
};
```

[This fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b22qybhd/) has the whole thing working.

Comment: Yes, just as @TAGraves writes. There is no reason for the algorithm to run more than twice since it executes the code line after line. And since if you enter an incorrect answer the first time, your safety check will get triggered and user will be prompted again. However, if they enter another incorrect answer, the code simply continues. That is why you need to include the code above - it will check the condition and if it is not correct, the function will run again. In terms of running the code, imagine playing a board game and going back 3 steps every time you roll 6. This is the same.

Comment: I understand how this is suposed to work but it doesent. This ends up happening: http://s23.postimg.org/e6hz8swhn/Capture.png

Comment: The problem is that you didn't change references to userChoice throughout the code. Look at my fiddle. Notice how after I declare the function, I make a variable `var choice = userChoice();` and then use `choice` wherever you had `userChoice` before.

Comment: Also, make sure you're doing `return userChoice();` for the first part of the conditional instead of just calling `userChoice()`.

Comment: Ok, i have changed so that it now calls the choice var but now it says its not defined. And can you a little bit more specific with the return of userChoice(); . Sorry if im being a drag but im just starting out.

Comment: I've just relised that you have put the link to the solved stuff. I will work from that. Tnx for all the help.

Comment: Cheers. Let me know if you have any problems or other questions. You're not being a drag - we're here to help.

Comment: Just one more thing. I understand everything about the code and got it to work. But that reference var choice = userChoice(); makes no sense to me. What is the reason it had to be called?

Comment: `userChoice` is a function that returns the prompt value; it is not a variable holding that value. If you never call the function, then the function will never run. `var choice = userChoice();` calls the function and then stores whatever the function returns in the `choice` variable. Notice how your last line, `compare(userChoice, computerChoice);` doesn't appear to do anything? If you store it in a variable like `var result = compare(userChoice, computerChoice);` then you can do `console.log(result)` and see whatever compare returned.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following

```
do  {
    userChoice = prompt("Do you choose rock, paper or scissors?");
} while (userChoice != "rock", "paper", "scissors")
```

Comment: This solution works as well as mine. Note that `userChoice != "rock", "paper", "scissors"` doesn't work - you need to change it to several statements conjoined by &&, as I did.